# spacy cannot load the model

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, spacy

I am trying to use spacy

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_vectors_web_lg')
```

However it fails with the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 3, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_vectors_web_lg')
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 15, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 112, in load_model
    return load_model_from_link(name, **overrides)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 129, in load_model_from_link
    return cls.load(**overrides)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/data/en_vectors_web_lg/__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 173, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 156, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 653, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 641, in <lambda>
    self.vocab.from_disk(p) and _fix_pretrained_vectors_name(self))),
  File "vocab.pyx", line 380, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.from_disk
  File "vectors.pyx", line 391, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 511, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "vectors.pyx", line 384, in spacy.vectors.Vectors.from_disk.load_vectors
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 419, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 681, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 112320492 into shape (1070971,300)
```

Please help me to fix the problem.

I use `conda` to manage environment

```
spacy validate

Installed models (spaCy v2.0.11)
/home/ubuntu/miniconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy

TYPE        NAME                  MODEL                 VERSION                                   
package     en-vectors-web-lg     en_vectors_web_lg     2.0.0    ✔      
package     en-core-web-sm        en_core_web_sm        2.0.0    ✔      
package     en-core-web-lg        en_core_web_lg        2.0.0    ✔      
link        en_vectors_web_lg     en_vectors_web_lg     2.0.0    ✔      
link        en                    en_core_web_sm        2.0.0    ✔      
link        en_core_web_lg        en_core_web_lg        2.0.0    ✔
```

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution online? The error seems pretty clear to me. The array that you are trying to reshape has more elements than the shape that you are loading into. I would look into how the data was created and how its being loaded or the shape inferred.

Comment: no clue on the Internet

Comment: This error usually indicates that *something* is not compatible – e.g. the combindation of spaCy, Thinc or numpy. This can happen if for some reason, your environment doesn't upgrade cleanly. [Here's a similar issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2312), which was solved by a clean environment. `conda update --all` sometimes also works wonders.

Comment: @InesMontani, upgrade didn't help